# How to return the groups from a double group by that have all categories on them in HiveQL

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, hiveql

I have this code in Hiveql and I want to return only the groups that have both Female and Male

```
select first_name, gender, count(*) from attributes  
group by first_name, gender
```

for example

```
name     gender   count
MICHAEL  FEMALE   10000
         MALE     11200
```

and not:

```
name     gender   count
BILLY    MALE     12000
MARY     FEMALE   800
```

Comment: Hi, in your example why there is no name in the second row? Do you want your output to display no name on the second row? On more thing, do you mean "groups" is the name which is used for both male and female? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `having`:

```
select first_name, count(*)
from attributes  
group by first_name
having min(gender) <> max(gender);
```

Comment: That works! just needed a line of code: 

"""select first_name, gender ,count(*) as cnt  from attributes  
right join
select first_name, count(*)
from attributes  
group by first_name
having min(gender) <> max(gender);"""

Answer (score 0):

The code above was right! just needed a line of code:

```
 select first_name, gender ,count(*) from attributes  
 right join
 select first_name, count(*)
 from attributes  
 group by first_name
 having min(gender) <> max(gender);
```